# Sencha Touch 2 Google Map does nothing

Tags: google-maps, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have a sencha touch 1 app I've just upgraded to sencha touch 2, and I've got everything to work except the google map.

In ST1, I added this line to index.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
```

Then I added this to a panel:

```
            {
                xtype: 'map',
                useCurrentLocation: false,
                fullscreen: false,
                layout: 'auto',
                id: 'jobmap',
                height: 400,
                mapOptions: {
                    zoom: 12,
                    navigationControl: true,
                    navigationControlOptions: 
                    {
                        style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.DEFAULT
                    }
                }                    
            }
```

In ST2, the docs say to still add the reference to index.html, though their forums also seem to say to use app.json. I've tried both using the above code and nothing appears on the panel. The controls before and after it appear adjacent to each other.

I've even just tried:

```
         {
                xtype: 'map',
                useCurrentLocation: true
            }
```

and I still get nothing.

Any ideas?

Comment: help me check out my post regarding Map, i need help pls thanks : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10748533/using-marker-to-spot-a-particular-address-in-a-map-sencha-touch-2-sencha-map/10758249#10758249

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The panel which contains your map should be set `layout: 'card'`.

Also, it's not necessary (or may cause errors) to set `fullscreen: false` or `layout: 'auto'`, just remove them from your map config.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks! ST is great but full of little gotchas :)

Comment: This is GREAT information that should be very evident in Sencha's docs. Sadly it's not.